# Как правильно разделить(рассплитить) строку python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Нужно получить название сайта из приходящего урла
Пример на входе:  https://site.com/some/some
Мне нужно: https://site.com/

Я могу рассплитить и пересобрать:

```
site = 'https://site.com/some/some'
site_spl = site.split('/')
site_sum = site_spl[0] + '//' + site_spl[2] + '/'
```

Но нет ли такого варианта, чтобы сразу обратиться к третьему слэшу и рассплитить по нему или как-то иначе сделать это изящнее?

Comment: site.rsplit("/", 2)[0] + "/"

Comment: Не подходит, т.к. справа может быть бесконечное количество слэшей

Comment: То есть, урл может быть и 'https ://site.com/some/some/some/some/some/some/some/some'

Answer (score 5):

Можно тоже самое сделать просто короче и чуть правильнее:

```
site = 'https://site.com/some/some'
print('/'.join(site.split('/')[:3]))
```

Вывод:

```
https://site.com
```

Или с помощью библиотеки:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

site = 'https://site.com/some/some'
url = urlparse(site)
print(f'{url.scheme}://{url.netloc}')
```

Вывод:

```
https://site.com
```

Если в конце нужен слеш - можно добавить его вручную через `+ '/'`.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте регулярное выражение

```
import re
reg = r'^((http[s]?|ftp):\/\/)?\/?([^\/\.]+\.)*?([^\/\.]+\.[^:\/\s\.]{2,3}(\.[^:\/\s\.]{2,3})?)(:\d+)?($|\/)'

s = 'https://site.com/some/some'

result = re.search(reg, s)

print (result.group(0))
```

Comment: Идея хорошая, но конкретно эта регулярка срабатывает неправильно. Она не ограничивается названием сайта и парсит больше

Comment: исправил код программы

Comment: вот сайт где модно баловаться в регулярными выражениями (https://regex101.com), вариантов полно

Comment: @АндрейКрузлик, мода - это баловство :)

Answer (score 1):

Через `find`:

```py
site = 'https://site.com/some/some'
res = site[:site.find('/', 2 + site.find('/'))]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pathlib import Path

site = 'https://site.com/some/some'

f = Path(site)
print(f.parts)
print(f.parts[2:])

# ('https:', 'site.com', 'some', 'some')
# ('some', 'some')
```

или еще вариант c регуляркой

```py
import re

regexp = re.compile(r'/+')

site = 'https://site.com/some/some'

parts = regexp.split(site)
print(parts)
print(parts[2:])

# ['https:', 'site.com', 'some', 'some']
# ['some', 'some']
```

Ну и немного дополню уже предложенный вариант:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

site = 'https://site.com/some/some'
url = urlparse(site)
print(f'{url.scheme = }', f'{url.netloc = }', f'{url.path = }', sep='\n')

# url.scheme = 'https'
# url.netloc = 'site.com'
# url.path = '/some/some'
```